# Stop iterating when an error rate on a vector is below a threshold

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using an iterative method to compute values of a vector. In each iteration the values in the vector change. After many iterations the values converges. I don't want to stop the iteration/loop based on the number of iterations, rather I want to stop when the an error rate is below a specific threshold.

My vector `V` has `n` elements. The sum of the elements of `V` is always 1. What I'm doing is that I keep an old copy of `V` and then a compute the new copy. Then I compute the difference between the two vectors, as `E = V_new - V_old`. Where all vectors are `numpy` arrays. So `E` here holds the differences between the old values and the new values. However at this point I'm not able to know what to do with the `E` and how to use it to stop the loop. One way I thought to solve this is by summing all the elements of `E` and then stop the loop when the value of the sum is below a threshold, but that resulted in a zero as the result of the sum in the very first iteration because some elements were negatives and other positives. Now I'm stuck!

Edit: I just thought of using the absolute value of `E`.

Comment: What is the algorithm? Scipy and networkx both implement algorithms that do precisely what you're asking for when doing things like pagerank.

Comment: @Elliott it's page rank indeed. Power iteration. But I need to do it on my own. I'm implementing the results of a paper

Comment: NetworkX is distributed with the BSD License, so you could copy/paste the networkx pagerank routine and modify it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand, but can't you try:

```
while abs(E).max() > epsilon:
```